# Меняется порядок ключей объекта при создании его копии

Tags: javascript

Решил задачку, где надо ключи сделать значением, а значения ключами, т.е из такого изначального объекта [image: введите сюда описание изображения] получилась его копия [image: введите сюда описание изображения], но почему изменился порядок ключей?

```
var newObj = {
    name: 'Татата',
    age: 100,
    gender: 'unknown'
}



function value_key (obj) {
    var copyObj = {};
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        copyObj[obj[keys[i]]] = keys[i];
    }
    return copyObj;

}

console.log(value_key(newObj));
```

Comment: это чудачество вашей консоли . а так порядок в новом объекте должен остаться тот же

Comment: Так вроде бы,  никакого порядка и нет. Об этом прямо пишут во всех учебниках. А консоль Хрома сортирует по имени ключа

Comment: Вообще говоря, получившийся порядок соответствует спецификации ES2015 - сначала числовые ключи, потом остальные в порядке добавления.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Значит все в порядке